# Can I substitute blackbelly rosefish for spiny lobster?

Tags: fish, seafood, crawfish

Can blackbelly rosefish ("cantarilho" in Portuguese) or HELICOLENUS DACTYLOPTERUS, a fish, be considered a substitute of spiny lobster ("lagosta" in Portuguese), a crustacean?

Some people say, after cooking a seafood rice with both, you can't differentiate the fish (fish loin only) from the lobster anymore.

Since the price for lobster is significantly higher than for the fish, I wonder how to detect if it was cooked with crustacean only, or was "stretched" with blackbelly rosefish?

[blackbelly rosefish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicolenus_dactylopterus#/media/File:Fish4271_-_Flickr_-_NOAA_Photo_Library.jpg)

<sup>source wikipedia.org</sup>

[spiny lobster](https://www.mundoecologia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/A-Lagosta-F%C3%AAmea-1.jpg)

<sup>source mundoecologia.com.br</sup>

Comment: Er, lobster and crawfish are two different animals, with different flavors.  Which are you looking for?

Comment: @FuzzyChef crawfish is what we have here in Portugal, updated the question

Comment: I think what @FuzzyChef is getting at is: are you asking if you can use the fish in the place of the crawfish, or are you asking if they taste different to each-other? If you cook both together then flavours blend and you may not be able to distinguish them.

Comment: Edited the title of the question to indicate crawfish per the comment above.

Comment: @FuzzyChef thanks, that title is much better to reflect what I had in mind

Comment: One more question for clarity -- and in the interest of getting you good answers -- are you specifically cooking seafood rice?

Comment: That's actually a picture of European freshwater crayfish (Austropotamobius pallipes), which is an endangered species. Crawfish is a name used in the USA for a different species.  They aren't the same.

Comment: @BillyKerr I have updated the picture (lagosta = lobster) and rephrased a bit my question to better point to what I'm actually wanting to know

Comment: That's what I would call a "spiny lobster". These are usually found in warmer waters of southern Europe, and in the Mediterranean. I've seen them for sale in Portugal and Spain  Usually the lobster we get here in the UK and other parts of northern Europe is the [common European lobster (Homarus_gammarus)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homarus_gammarus) which have large meaty claws, They're purple or blue, and turn orange when cooked.

Comment: @BillyKerr definitely not Homarus grammarus, but the orange one on the updated picture

Comment: Yeah, your one is called a "spiny lobster" in English. Very confusing!!!

Comment: Spiny lobsters, also known as langustas, langouste, or rock lobsters, are a family (Palinuridae) of about 60 species, maybe I should edit it into langouste, which is the closest to the portuguese word?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132946/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-vickel).

Answer (score 1):

What's your goal?  Both can make an excellent base for a seafood based rice dish.  In a side by side, I bet you would be able to tell the difference.  If you are trying to do this surreptitiously, maybe not a good idea.  More importantly, does it matter?  Why not just make blackbelly roefish rice with broth...call it blackbelly roefish rice with broth...make it delicious, and enjoy?  If you are suspicious that you were tricked, maybe ask the chef.